# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal argument undefined at e.exports (content.js:33:95534)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im building an MERN todo app from a course and notice this error in the console. I look at everything and compared my code with the instructors and they are the same.  Then I notice that I get the same error no matter what page I'm on in Chrome.  I don't get the error in other browsers.

Here is the full error:

```
content.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal argument undefined
    at e.exports (content.js:33:95534)
    at content.js:73:1477043
    at p (content.js:73:185751)
    at Generator._invoke (content.js:73:185504)
    at Generator.next (content.js:73:186114)
    at r (content.js:73:192157)
    at s (content.js:73:192360)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

I just had the same error, in my case a chrome extension called Coupert was the problem, so I disabled it for now. Content.js scripts are used by chrome extensions to modify or interact with the content of pages, so it's highly likely that an extension is causing your error to pop up.

Comment: Thank you. Coupert browser extension was the culprit for me as well.